# copying char array into another array gives garbage value

Tags: c++, arrays, string, character-encoding, garbage

I'm making a simple encryption program on the bases of ascii. below is my code and I'm not sure why I'm getting a garbage value at the end while printing the copied string.

[output results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnYXj.png)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

void encrypt(char []);
void convertToAscii(char [], char []);
int main()
{
    char userString [] ="This is a string";
    const int size= sizeof(userString);
    char copyString[size];
    convertToAscii(userString, copyString);
    cout<<copyString;
    _getch();
    return 0;
}

void convertToAscii(char s[], char* cs)
{
    for(int i=0; s[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        int x = s[i];
        x= x+3;
        char y= x;
        cs[i]=y;
        cout<< x<<" "<<y<<"\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: basically converting one char o another on the bases of ASCII so +3 is converting the ASCII off that particular char to another char.i.e T will become W amd so on.

Comment: And, '}' + 3 will be out of range for ASCII. To wrap around, `char y = x % 128;` So, '}' becomes '\x00' (␀), '~' becomes '\x01' (␁) and '\x7F' (␡) becomes '\x02' (␂).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just append the terminating zero to the destination string

```
void convertToAscii(char s[], char* cs)
{
    size_t i = 0;

    for(; s[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        int x = s[i];
        x= x+3;
        char y= x;
        cs[i]=y;
        cout<< x<<" "<<y<<"\n";
    }

    cs[i] = '\0';
}
```

Another way is the following

```
char * convertToAscii( cosnt char *s, char *cs)
^^^^^^                 ^^^^^
{
    char *p = cs;

    for ( ; ( *cs = *s ) != '\0'; ++cs, ++s ) *cs += 3;

    return p;  
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In C you have to null-terminate your strings.  You recognize that because your `convertToAscii()` function is looking for the null-terminator in the input; but it's not putting an null-terminator on the output, so methods like cout's `operator<<` don't know where the value at `copyString` ends.

Of course in order for the `convertToAscii` function to null-terminate your string, you need to allocate additional space for `'\0'` in the caller:

```
char copyString[size + 1];
//                   ^^^
```

Comment: `sizeof(userString)` is `strlen(userString) + 1`. Hence, `char copyString[size];` should be adequate.

Comment: May want to mention that `char copyString[size + 1]` is a VLA and not standard C++.